# ffmpeg nearest-neighbor downscale not working as expected

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to downscale a video with nearest-neighbour scaling, but the results are very poor.

To try and get to the bottom of it, I created [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeLkN.png) which is a repeating pattern of various colours. The expected result is that the output image, when downscaled from 1080p to 360p, is solid green (#00ff00). Or possibly red, if it samples from the top-left instead of the centre.

Instead, the resulting image is green with vertical bars of #25e525 and #44c383, neither of which are present anywhere in the original image.

[image]

I've applied various other things to my command, as seen below, but it makes no difference.

`ffmpeg -i 1080.png -vf scale=-1:360:flags=neighbor+accurate_rnd:sws_dither=none -pix_fmt rgb24 360.png`

Upscaling works fine - it's just downscaling that goes wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After some more back-and-forth with Bing, it seems `zscale` works far better than `scale`.

`ffmpeg -i 1080.png -vf "zscale=-1:360:filter=point" 360.png`

With video, add `format=pix_fmts=rgb24,` to the start of the `vf` chain.

Answer (score 0):

It also seems that `full_chroma_inp` works with `scale`. Another option in case `zscale` isn't available.

`ffmpeg -i 1080.png -vf scale=-1:360:flags=neighbor+full_chroma_inp 360.png`